# Entity Framework Core PostgreSQL hstore queries

Tags: postgresql, npgsql, hstore, ef-core-3.1

I need generate query for value in hstore column

```
var collection = await _context.Settings
.Select(b => new
{
    SettingId = b.SettingId,
    SettingParentId = b.SettingParentId,
    SettingValue = (b.SettingValue.ContainsKey('key') ? b.SettingValue['key'] : "")
})
.OrderBy(x => x.SettingId)
```

But is no best way, exist any way to realize this query to translate to this sql?

```
SELECT setting_id, 
       setting_parent_id,
       setting_value -> 'key' AS setting_value
FROM settings
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Npgsql EFCore provider doesn't currently do any translations for the hstore type. This is mainly because extended support is already present [for the PostgreSQL jsonb type](http://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/json.html#querying-json-columns) (including what you want to do), and that type is much more powerful than hstore. Consider switching from hstore to jsonb.

[This is the issue](https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/212) tracking query translation for hstore.

Comment: hstore is perfect because i use in select expression, i need select one key for parameter.  the sample jsonb is in where expression. Exist translation for jsonb in select expression?

Comment: You should be able to achieve the same with [using JsonDocument](http://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/json.html?tabs=data-annotations%2Cjsondocument) mapping to jsonb. This mapping mode is appropriate for schema-less scenarios where the key itself can be parameterized.

Comment: @jrocha76: jsonb can do everything that hstore can and then more. You would just use `setting_value ->> 'key'` instead of `setting_value -> 'key'`

Comment: I try public JsonElement SettingValue { get; set; } and Select(b => new
                {
                    b.SettingId,
                    b.SettingParentId,
                    SettingValue = b.SettingValue.GetProperty(lang)
                }), but when value is null --> throw error

Comment: @jrocha76 better continue discussing that in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61995777/entity-framework-core-postgresql-json-query and leave this question about hstore.

Comment: Finally is the best option use bjson type, more efficient and easy