# Entity Framework Core PostgreSQL json query

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql

Always return empty results

```
var collection = await _context.Settings
.Select(s => new
{
    s.SettingId,
    s.SettingParentId,
    SettingValue = s.SettingValue.GetProperty(lang)
})
.Where(s => EF.Functions.JsonExists(s.SettingValue, lang))
.ToListAsync();
```

I try return only key from json but always return empty, when remove "select" works fine but i need only one key

This is the model

```
public class Setting
{
    public string SettingId { get; set; }
    public string SettingParentId { get; set; }
    public JsonElement SettingValue { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Which version of EF Core are you using? Can you also please post your minimal model?

Comment: I use last version "EF Core 3", this is a bug

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're trying to do: your code gets a property called `lang` in the JSON document, and then checks if another property called `lang` exists within that - are you sure that's what you want? If you just want to check if `lang` exists in the JSON document, try removing GetProperty(lang) from the anonymous type projection.

Comment: the json is {es:"valor", en:"value") i need get only key "es" if exists

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like the following:

```cs
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        await using var ctx = new BlogContext();
        await ctx.Database.EnsureDeletedAsync();
        await ctx.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync();

        var lang = "es";

        var collection = await ctx.Settings
            .Where(s => EF.Functions.JsonExists(s.SettingValue, lang))
            .Select(s => new
            {
                s.SettingId,
                s.SettingParentId,
                SettingValue = s.SettingValue.GetProperty(lang).GetString()
            })
            .ToListAsync();

        foreach (var i in collection)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{i.SettingId}: {i.SettingValue}");
        }
    }
}

public class BlogContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Setting> Settings { get; set; }

    static ILoggerFactory ContextLoggerFactory
        => LoggerFactory.Create(b => b.AddConsole().AddFilter("", LogLevel.Information));

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        => optionsBuilder
            .UseNpgsql(@"Host=localhost;Username=test;Password=test")
            .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
            .UseLoggerFactory(ContextLoggerFactory);

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Setting>().HasData(new Setting
        {
            SettingId = "1",
            SettingValue = JsonDocument.Parse(@"{ ""es"" : ""valor""}").RootElement
        });
    }
}

public class Setting
{
    public string SettingId { get; set; }
    public string SettingParentId { get; set; }
    public JsonElement SettingValue { get; set; }
}
```